# Populate a multidimensional array of rooms with another multidimensional array of names

Tags: php

I'm trying to assign people `$prides` from one multidimensional array to rooms `$campus` in another multidimensional array.

The people in the first array are first grouped into coded arrays indicating their building preference, room preference, and gender.

I need to first match the appropriate arrays, i.e. get the arrays of people for large rooms in building a which would be `bldgaLargeF` and `bldgaLargeM`.  Then fill each room until I run out of Females, leave the remaining bunks empty, and then populate the next room with Males.  If I run out of rooms before I run out of people, the remaining people need to be placed into a homeless array.

The number of rooms is fixed, the number of people, or even the number of groups in the people array can vary.

How do I write this without creating a loopy mess or building hundreds of nested if and case statements?

```
<?php
/*
    - multidimensional array of people
        - group by requirements:  building, room size, smoking, roommate smoking preference
    - multidimensional array of rooms
        - group by building, size, bunks
    - break arrays into sets
        - count number of people in each set
        - reserve block of required rooms
        - assign remaining people to homeless array
*/
$prides = array(
    "acbLargeM" => array("Matt","Jason","Tim","Jeffrey","Ed","Jim"),
    "acbLargeF" => array("Andrea","Ashley","Renae","Dena","Amanda","Amie","Angie"),
    "acbSmallM" => array("Eric","Matt"),
    "acbSmallF" => array(),
    "tbnLargeM" => array("Bill","David","David","Eric"),
    "tbnLargeF" => array("Dawn","Linda","Heather","Heidi"),
    "tbnSmallM" => array("Joe","Keith","Michael","Jeff","Jack","Michael","Ronn","Tony"),
    "tbnSmallF" => array("Melanie","Melissa","Tara","Victoria"));
$campus = array(
    "acb" => array(
        "Large" => array(
            "101" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "103" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "105" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "107" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "109" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "111" => array("", "", "", "")
        ),
        "Small" => array(
            "102" => array("", ""),
            "104" => array("", ""),
            "106" => array("", ""),
            "108" => array("", ""),
            "110" => array("", ""),
            "112" => array("", "")
        )),
    "tbn" => array(
        "Large" => array(
            "101" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "103" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "105" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "107" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "109" => array("", "", "", ""),
            "111" => array("", "", "", "")
        ),
        "Small" => array(
            "102" => array("", ""),
            "104" => array("", ""),
            "106" => array("", ""),
            "108" => array("", ""),
            "110" => array("", ""),
            "112" => array("", "")
        ))
    );
    $homeless = array();

// count prides
    $acbLargeMcount = count($prides['acbLargeM']);
    $acbLargeFcount = count($prides['acbLargeF']);
    $acbSmallMcount = count($prides['acbSmallM']);
    $acbSmallFcount = count($prides['acbSmallF']);
    $tbnLargeMcount = count($prides['tbnLargeM']);
    $tbnLargeFcount = count($prides['tbnLargeF']);
    $tbnSmallMcount = count($prides['tbnSmallM']);
    $tbnSmallFcount = count($prides['tbnSmallF']);

    // build room arrays that match sizes of pride arrays
    $keys = array_keys($prides);
    $iterations = count($array[$keys[0]]);

    foreach($campus as $building => $buildings) {
        foreach($buildings as $size => $sizes) {
            $y=0;
            foreach($sizes as $roomno => $room) {
                $thisRoomDesc = $building . $size;
                switch($thisRoomDesc){
                    case "acbLarge":
                        $bunks = count($room);
                        for($x = 0; $x < $bunks; $x++){
                            $room[$x] = $prides["acbLargeF"][$y] . "\r";
                            // this isn't working.
                        }
                        break;    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($campus);
    print_r($keys);
    echo $iterations;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to something like a MySQL database? This would immensely simplify ordering and assigning properties to your students

Comment: It might make sense to assign the different properties to the individual students, as you would with a database table; so it would be like prides["studentX"]=>array("roomsize"=>"small", "gender" =>"female")... etc to start with

Comment: Why do you have a concat \r above the comment that it isn't working?

Comment: also, your `$room[$x] = $prides["acbLargeF"][$y]` is always equal to `$room[$x] = $prides["acbLargeF"][0]` in that line. (you define $y as 0 and never increase or change it otherwise) - I have a feeling you would want to do more than just repeating "Andrea" over and over

Comment: These arrays are derived from data in a mysql database.  The arrays of people are run through an algorithm using the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient to group people with similar responses to a form together.  I built this as an example of the specific problem I am having, which is wrapping my head around merging two arrays together, while keeping distinct groups apart... in other words, putting women and men together in a small room in the wrong building needs to be avoided.  The counts and specifically the for loop is where I'm stuck, and it can all be scrapped.

Comment: The line `$room[x] = $prides["acbLargeF"][$y]` is exactly where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

- Work with the `$prides` array and remove every person that gets into a room. So in the end the homeless are the people remaining in this array.
- Use the `$campus` array by reference and fill it directly.

```
foreach($campus as $building => &$buildings) {
    foreach($buildings as $size => &$sizes) {
        foreach($sizes as $roomno => &$room) {
            // build the pride string of this room
            $roomPride = $building . $size;
            // check if there is the pride of this room defined - if not: continue with the next room
            if(!array_key_exists($roomPride.'F',$prides) && !array_key_exists($roomPride.'M',$prides)) continue;
            // determine the gender for this room
            $roomGender = (!empty($prides[$roomPride.'F'])) ? 'F' : 'M';
            // loop over the room size
            foreach($room as &$space) {
                // check weather there are people left that fit this room's "settings"
                if(!empty($prides[$roomPride.$roomGender])) {
                    // if so, place the people in and remove them from the $prides array
                    $space = $prides[$roomPride.$roomGender][0];
                    array_splice($prides[$roomPride.$roomGender], 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// flatten the $prides array to get all homeless people
$homeless = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $prides);
```